# Get-AzConsumptionBudget shows incorrect/incomplete data

Tags: azure, powershell

Good Morning,

I've tried to get current usage and forecast for multiple subscriptions (just the $ amount for one and the other - not interested in detailed results). The best/only way I've found is to use "Get-AzConsumptionBudget" however for multiple subscriptions I get result 0, but when I navigate in Portal there is actual consumption (sometimes quite big).

I was wondering if there is a way to get current usage and forecasted (so exactly what is shown on Portal/Subscription overview) in Powershell?

Thank you

Comment: Billing REST APi dont works for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-AzConsumptionBudget will only provide you budget information. It's showing zero because you have not configured any budget information for these subscriptions. What you should be using is the [Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.billing/get-azconsumptionusagedetail?view=azps-6.0.0).

However, based on the findings in the comment section below, if budgets are set for all subscriptions, it seems that using `Get-AzConsumptionBudget` will provide the budget consumption.

For the cost forecast - unfortunately Powershell or Az CLI do not yet support that. If you still need to get it, you can try the [REST API for forecast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/forecast/usage#subscriptionforecast) but it will require a bit of work, including creating a [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: Technically get-AzConsumptionBudget will show current usage...but as you said, only when budget is configured (with .CurrentSpend).

Also, good point on the Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail - it can show fairly accurate current usage with:  
`Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail  -BillingPeriodName $CurrentMonth  | Measure-Object PretaxCost -Sum'`

Unfortunately still cannot figure out how to get forecasted

Comment: Yes you're right - it will only show the current usage after you configure the budget for that subscription since budget consumption is part of budget information. I have updated my answer with some more information about the REST API for forecast. If you're satisfied with the answers/information, give it an upvote or mark as answer - whichever applicable! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Ked-Mardemootoo mentioned current usage can be achieved with:
`Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail  -BillingPeriodName $CurrentMonth  | Measure-Object PretaxCost -Sum`